# Are there restrictions on MongoDB collections property names?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've a document structure wich contains a property named `shares` which is an array of objects.
Now I tried to match all documents where `shared` contains the matching `_account` string with dot notation (`shares._account`).

It's not working but it seems it's because of the `_` char in front of property `_account`.
So if I put the string to search for inside the name property in that object everything works fine with dot notation.

Are there any limitations on property names?
Thought an `_` is allowed because the `id` has it also in mongodb and for me it's a kind of convention to daclare bindings.

Example:

```
    // Collection Item example
{
  "_account": { "$oid" : "526fd2a571e1e13b4100000c" },
  "_id": { "$oid" : "5279456932db6adb60000003" },
  "name": "shared.jpg",
  "path": "/upload/24795-4ui95s.jpg",
  "preview": "/img/thumbs/24795-4ui95s.jpg",
  "shared": false,
  "shares": [
    {
      "name": "526fcb177675f27140000001",
      "_account": "526fcb177675f27140000001"
    },
    {
      "name": "tim",
      "_account": "526fd29871e1e13b4100000b"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    "grüngelb",
    "farbe"
  ],
  "type": "image/jpeg"
},
```

I tried to get the item with following query:

```
// Query example
{
    "$or": [
        {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "type": {
                        "$in": ["image/jpeg"]
                    }
                }, {
                    "shares._account": "526fcb177675f27140000001"    // Not working
                    //"shares.name": "526fcb177675f27140000001"    //   Working

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that `$and` can be omitted and `$or` is pointless `"image/jpeg"` != `"image/jpg"`:

```
db.foo.find({
    "type": {"$in": ["image/jpeg"]},
    "shares._account": "526fcb177675f27140000002"
})
```

Or if you really want old one:

```
db.foo.find({
    "$or": [
        {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "type": {
                        "$in": ["image/jpeg"]
                    }
                }, {
                    "shares._account": "526fcb177675f27140000002"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Both will return example document.

Comment: not at me.. also with a reduced query I get no response. But if I query for value of name I get a result {
    "$or": [
        {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "shares._account": "526fcb177675f27140000001"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Could you provide reproducible example (insert + query)? Right now your query won't match `type` field of example document.

Comment: Could you check if this works: `db.foobar.insert({foo: [{_bar: 1}, {_bar: 2}]});  db.foobar.find({"foo._bar" :1})`

Answer (score 0):

Your current query has some unnecessarily complicated constructs:

- you don't need the `$or` and `$and` clauses ("and" is the default behaviour)
- you are matching a single value using `$in`

The query won't find match the sample document because your query doesn't match the data:

- the `type` field you are looking for is "image/jpg" but your sample document has "image/jpeg"
- the `shares._account` value you are looking for is "526fcb177675f27140000001" but your sample document doesn't include this.

A simplified query that should work is:

```
db.shares.find(
    {
        "type": "image/jpeg",
        "shares._account": "526fcb177675f27140000002" 
    }
)
```

Comment: that was a typo also got no match.

Comment: If you've fixed both mismatches for query vs document and are still not seeing a result, can you provide some details on your specific MongoDB server version and O/S?  It would also be useful to note that you've found errors in the original question text rather than correcting them.  If you iterate on the question the answers are pointing out actual problems that have been fixed.

Comment: It's the latest mongodb from macports on OSX 10.8